# How to trigger only one specif bloc builder?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I'm creating a chat app, and in the sending message feature I'm handeling the different states that a message can be at using bloc (the different states are: sent, delivered and seen), but the issue is since I'm using `BlocBuilder` in order to handle the ui it's rebuilding the UI for all the messages that were sent. Let me show you an example to understand more, first here is my widget:

```dart
class MessageItemWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Message message;
  final Alignment alignment;
  final BorderRadius borderRadius;
  final TextStyle chatStyle;
  final Color color;
  const MessageItemWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.message,
    required this.alignment,
    required this.borderRadius,
    required this.chatStyle,
    required this.color,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<MessagesCubit, MessagesState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        if (state is MessageSending) {
          return Align(
            alignment: alignment,
            child: UnconstrainedBox(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: 20,
                      vertical: 10,
                    ),
                    constraints: BoxConstraints(
                      maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.55,
                    ),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: borderRadius,
                      color: color,
                    ),
                    child: Text(
                      message.content,
                      style: chatStyle,
                    ),
                  ),
                  const Icon(
                    Icons.check,
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    size: 15,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        } else if (state is MessageSent) {
          return Align(
            alignment: alignment,
            child: UnconstrainedBox(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: 20,
                      vertical: 10,
                    ),
                    constraints: BoxConstraints(
                      maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.55,
                    ),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: borderRadius,
                      color: color,
                    ),
                    child: Text(
                      message.content,
                      style: chatStyle,
                    ),
                  ),
                  const Row(
                    children: [
                      Icon(
                        Icons.check,
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        size: 15,
                      ),
                      Icon(
                        Icons.check,
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        size: 15,
                      ),
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        } else {
          return const SizedBox();
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

In a nutshell, what it does is: if the message is sent it shows one check icon under the message, and when the message has been delivered it shows two check icons under the message. But whenever a message has been sent, it rebuilds the UI of all the previous already sent messages, here is an example:

[image]

In the image above, all the messages have been delivered successfully. But whenever I sent a new message, this happens:

[image]

The already delievered messages are shown that they are being sent but in fact they have been delivered previously, how can I trigger only a specif bloc for the specifi message.

Here is my cubit:

```dart
class MessagesCubit extends Cubit<MessagesState> {
  ChatRepository chatRepository;
  MessagesCubit(this.chatRepository) : super(MessagesInitial());

  Future<void> getMessages(
    BuildContext context, {
    required UserChat client,
    required UserChat supplier,
  }) async {
    emit(MessagesLoading());

    final failureOrStreamOfMessages =
        await chatRepository.getMessages(client: client, supplier: supplier);

    failureOrStreamOfMessages.fold(
      (failure) => emit(MessageError(mapFailureToMessage(failure, context))),
      (streamOfMessages) => streamOfMessages.listen(
        (messages) => emit(MessagesLoaded(messages)),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> sendMessage(BuildContext context, Message message) async {
    emit(MessageSending());

    final failureOrUnit = await chatRepository.sendMessage(message);

    failureOrUnit.fold(
      (failure) => emit(MessageError(mapFailureToMessage(failure, context))),
      (_) => emit(MessageSent()),
    );
  }
}
```

and here are my states:

```dart
abstract class MessagesState extends Equatable {
  const MessagesState();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class MessagesInitial extends MessagesState {}

// reading messages

abstract class ReadingMessagesState extends MessagesState {
  const ReadingMessagesState();
}

class MessagesLoading extends ReadingMessagesState {}

class MessagesLoaded extends ReadingMessagesState {
  final List<Message> messages;

  const MessagesLoaded(this.messages);

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [messages];
}

class MessagesError extends ReadingMessagesState {
  final String message;

  const MessagesError(this.message);

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [message];
}

// writing messages

abstract class WritingMessagesState extends MessagesState {
  const WritingMessagesState();
}

class MessageSending extends WritingMessagesState {}

class MessageSent extends WritingMessagesState {}

class MessageError extends WritingMessagesState {
  final String message;

  const MessageError(this.message);

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [message];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your `Message` model looks like, but lets assume it has a unique `Id` field. If not, you can add one. You could pass that into any `WritingMessagesState` state that you emit. Then use the `buildWhen` feature of the `BlocBuilder` to filter rebuilds only when the message that message id from the widget matches the message Id of the `state`.

eg.

```
abstract class WritingMessagesState extends MessagesState {
  WritingMessagesState({required this.id});

  final String id; // add this
}

class MessageSending extends WritingMessagesState {
  MessageSending({required super.id});
}

class MessageSent extends WritingMessagesState {
  MessageSent({required super.id});
}

class MessageError extends WritingMessagesState {
  MessageError({required super.id, required this.message});
  final String message;

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [message];
}
```

Then an example of your `emit` would look like this

```
  emit(MessageSending(id: message.id));
```

Then add the `buildWhen` to your BlocBuilder

```
    return BlocBuilder<MessagesCubit, MessagesState>(
     buildWhen: (previous, current) => current.id == message.id, // this will prevent all the other widgets from building
      builder: (context, state) {
    ...
```